# Microsoft interop.excel dll not allowing to create when the site hosted on IIS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Here my Imports.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat
```

This is create a object to imported Excel

```
Dim xlAppToExport As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkSheetToExport As Excel.Worksheet
```

when i executing a file from local its working fine and creating excel.

when i host that same project to IIS and executing. It return the error on line at execction time.

```
Dim xlAppToExport As Excel.Application
xlAppToExport = New Excel.Application
```

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).**

If any of them know. Help me.

Comment: Have you tried changing the account that the IIS app pool is running under?

Comment: No. Normally i executed

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely expected that it doesn't work when run inside of a non-interactive service like IIS. [Microsoft say so themselves](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> ...
>
> Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA).
>
> ...
>
> In addition to these issues, one of the following common errors may occur when you try to automate Office server-side:
>
> ...
>
> E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005): Access denied

Consider [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Import the below references.

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat
```

Here, these two imports are newly added

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

It allow us to generate a microsoft Interop excel report remotely.

It's working fine for me.